# selecting different values from two lines in shell

Tags: shell, grep, tr

I am running

```
echo "dis clusqmgr(*) suspend"|runmqsc QMGR1
```

to get the following output, but I would like to remove some of it. I have tried using `egrep` and `cut` but cannot get the desired result.

Original Output:

```
1 : dis clusqmgr(*) suspend
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
CLUSQMGR(GWD1)                       CHANNEL(TO.GWD1.SSL)
CLUSTER(CLUSD)                        SUSPEND(NO)
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
CLUSQMGR(GWD2)                       CHANNEL(TO.GWD2.SSL)
CLUSTER(CLUSD)                        SUSPEND(NO)
```

Desired output:

```
CLUSQMGR(GWD1) SUSPEND(NO)
CLUSQMGR(GWD2) SUSPEND(NO)
```

Command I am using to achieve this:

```
echo "dis clusqmgr(*) suspend"|runmqsc QMGR1|egrep 'CLUSQMGR|SUSPEND'| tr ')' '\n' | grep "CLUSQMGR(" | cut -f 2  -d ")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "dis clusqmgr(*) suspend"|runmqsc QMGR1|egrep 'CLUSQMGR|SUSPEND'|paste -  - | awk '{print $1,$4}'
```

is giving me the desired output as

CLUSQMGR(GWD1) SUSPEND(NO)
CLUSQMGR(GWD2) SUSPEND(NO)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat t.txt
1 : dis clusqmgr(*) suspend
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
CLUSQMGR(GWD1)                       CHANNEL(TO.GWD1.SSL)
CLUSTER(CLUSD)                        SUSPEND(NO)
AMQ8441: Display Cluster Queue Manager details.
CLUSQMGR(GWD2)                       CHANNEL(TO.GWD2.SSL)
CLUSTER(CLUSD)                        SUSPEND(NO)
```

.

```
$ awk '/^CLUSQMGR/{clusqmgr=$1;t=1}t&&/^CLUSTER/{t=0;print clusqmgr, $2}' t.txt
CLUSQMGR(GWD1) SUSPEND(NO)
CLUSQMGR(GWD2) SUSPEND(NO)
```

So

```
$ echo "dis clusqmgr(*) suspend" | runmqsc QMGR1 | awk '/^CLUSQMGR/{clusqmgr=$1;t=1}t&&/^CLUSTER/{t=0;print clusqmgr, $2}'
```

should yield your desired results.

Comment: It isn't giving me the result. No output is being displayed when i run this command.